# openssl decryption sometimes work

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I worked on this [problem](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~jrblack/class/csci6268/f09/hw/proj0.pdf). My code works if I try to decrypt a small phrase I encrypted like "hello there" but it doesn't work for given cipher text. I am new to openssl and I can't find what's wrong.

```
int main ()
{
    int i, j, k, ret, m;
    char pwd[4];
    char lower_alphabet[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<26; j++)
        {
            for(k=0; k<26; k++)
            {
                char cmd[70] = "openssl enc -aes128 -base64 -d -in cipher.enc -pass pass:";
                snprintf(pwd, sizeof(pwd), "%c%c%c", lower_alphabet[i], lower_alphabet[j], lower_alphabet[k]);
                strncat (cmd, pwd, 3);
                if ((ret = system(cmd)) == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n%s\n",pwd);
                    scanf ("%d", &m);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So my code tries all the possible password values and everytime openssl exits successfully it stops for user input.

Answer (score 1):

The correct password is 'yes':

```
$ openssl enc -aes128 -base64 -d -in cipher.enc -pass pass:yes
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzBIH8Frq-8&feature=player_embedded
```

---

I find it out by brute force:

1. try to decode the cipher.enc message with all the possible combination of three lowercase letters, by this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   for a in {a..z}; do
       for b in {a..z}; do
           for c in {a..z}; do
               echo -e "\n"
               openssl enc -aes128 -base64 -d -in cipher.enc -pass pass:$a$b$c
               echo -e "\nPASSWD: $a$b$c\n"
           done
       done
   done
   ```
2. run this script and find out all the long enough word-like string by the following command

   ```
   $ egrep -an --color '.*[[:alpha:]]{8,}' all.txt 
   6401:??l$?? f?T^0?@fJ8)?f?℗???uuEb??KFrVw????߁?LHtsQyfe?
                                                           C5y
   56180:?RCpWmnuWЇ_?y???\߱???cg???V?ߥŕ??{?GyD_?ڼZ???JN+;#?
   85793:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzBIH8Frq-8&feature=player_embedded
   ```
3. and Bingo, looks like I find out the `secret-message`. I can check this by encoding it with password 'yes' and comparing the result with `cipher.enc`, there are the same. Problem solved!

---

By the way, looks like `openssl` return zero is not a sufficient condition to find out the right password, because password 'anw' also made `openssl` return zero.

Comment: "looks like openssl return zero is not a sufficient condition..." - right. The only way to truly tell is to use an authentication tag over the cipher text and iv. You got a false positive because the padding happened to be correct, and that's a weak confirmation (Padding Oracles FTW!).